# Prioritize stream filter functions in Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am seeking for an option to filter in-streams but using priorities.

The following is the pseudo code:

```
results.stream().filter(prio1).ifNotFound(filter(prio2)).collect(toList())
```

The list of results shall be filtered by first criteria called "`prio1`" and if there ain't no match found the second filter shall be applied to try filter on second criteria called `prio2` and then the results shall be collected

How do I achive this in Java 8 using streams?

I am looking for a one-liner in stream.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by `ifNotFound`.

Comment: Can you say in which condition the second filter prio2 is not going to be applied?

Comment: all items shall be frist matched to prio1 and if no found then match again all items to prio2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to `stream()` your results twice, but the following should work as a one-liner:

```
results.stream().filter(results.stream().anyMatch(prio1) ? prio1 : prio2).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(Credit to [flakes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43552238/7256039) for first publishing a multiple-liner using a similar strategy.)

**Edit:** Since some excellent new answers have come to light, I thought I would offer a short defense of this multiple-stream / `anyMatch` strategy making reference to certain other parts of this thread:

- [As pointed out by eckes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43552040/prioritize-stream-filter-functions-in-java/43552238#comment74156760_43552238), `anyMatch` is optimized to return early and thus minimal time is spent reading the extra stream (especially for the case where `prio1` is likely to match). In fact, `anyMatch` will only read the whole stream in the fallback (`prio2`) case, so for the average run you are only iterating through one-and-a-fraction list lengths.
- Using the `Collectors.groupingBy(...)` method constructs a Map and two Lists in every case, while the approach above only creates at most a single List. The difference in memory overhead here will become quite significant as the size of `results` increases. The grouping is done for the entire stream, so even if the very first element happens to pass `prio1`, every element has to be checked against `prio1.or(prio2)` *and then* against `prio1` once more.
- `groupingBy` does not account for the case where `prio1` and `prio2` are not mutually exclusive. If `prio2.test(e)` can return `true` for some `e` which passes `prio1`, such elements will be missing within the fallback `prio2` list. Using `anyMatch` and one filter at a time avoids this problem.
- The line length and complexity of the above method seems far more manageable to me.

Comment: is there a way to write it into a one-liner without multiple iterations?

Comment: i like ur answer, but lets try to optimize it to run it once somehow

Comment: Working on an idea.. I'm on mobile so hang on :)

Comment: Ok, so here's the explanation why you *will* have to stream your `results` more than once. Checking whether `prio1` applies to at least one element of the list is a "terminal operation," meaning that the stream is no longer usable. You can avoid streaming the list twice in the case that `prio1` matches successfully, but that requires a considerably longer line: `Optional.of(results.stream().filter(prio1).collect(Collectors.toList())).filter(list -> !list.isEmpty()).orElseGet(() -> results.stream().filter(prio2).collect(Collectors.toList()))` (Hope I didn't miss any parens there!)

Comment: hmm i see i was hoping there would be some kind of hack using stream.reduce or stream.peek.. but thanks man, i marked it as theee answer, nice approach

Comment: @Ckkn It's possible if you're desperate enough: `results.stream().filter(prio1.or(prio2)).collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(prio1)).entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.reverseOrder())).map(Map.Entry::getValue).filter(list -> !list.isEmpty()).findFirst().orElse(Collections.emptyList());`

Comment: @shmosel you don't need to be _that_ desperate though ;-)

Comment: I figured someone would come up with a clever solution like that... kudos for taking the time! Technically you call `stream` twice though....

Comment: It's not streaming `results` again, just a two-element entry set.

Answer (score 4):

Just another approach that does not use `anyMatch`, but rather groups the entries before operating on the results.

```
Optional.of(results.stream()
                   .filter(prio1.or(prio2))
                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(prio1::test)))
        .map(map -> map.getOrDefault(true, map.get(false)))
        .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

I used `Optional` so that you have a "one liner" (just formatted it, so that it gets more readable). Instead of `ifPresent` you could also just use `orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)` and save the result into a `List<String>`.

The [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) puts all `prio1`-matching entries from the `prio1` and `prio2` filtered entries into the key `true` and the remaining `prio2`-matching entries into `false`. If we haven't any entries in `true`, then the `prio2`-filtered entries are returned as default. If there aren't any `prio1` or `prio2`-matching results, nothing happens.

Note that if you return the `Map` directly then you only have all `prio2`-matching entries in `false` if your filters are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Ohhh, this is cool! Clever use of `groupingBy`. Thanks for teaching me something new :)

Comment: Very nice, much better than my hack. Too bad you can't use `partitioningBy()`. The `map()` function is a bit unnecessarily clever though. `.map(map -> map.getOrDefault(true, map.get(false)))` is equivalent in function and performance, only slightly longer, and much more readable, IMO.

Comment: @shmosel you could also use `partitioningBy`, but then you need to check that the list there is empty, whereas now we just check for `null`. You are right... `getOrDefault` is more readable here... will change that...

Answer (score 1):

Just make a condition:

```
final List<Foo> foo;
if (results.stream().anyMatch(prio1)) {
    foo = results.stream().filter(prio1).collect(Collectors.toList());
} else {
    foo = results.stream().filter(prio2).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If you really want a one liner then you can do the following, but there's no way to get around streaming the list twice. I would argue that the `if/else` version is cleaner and easier to maintain.

```
final List<Foo> foo = results.stream()
    .filter(results.stream().anyMatch(prio1)? prio1 : prio2)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: it shall be a one liner... no if else

Comment: You can make it a one liner by mapping the condition into a attribute, but I don't think that having a one liner makes it any better compared to the above conditional (no: anyMatch IS optimized it will return early and that's good for the case where prio1 is likely.

Comment: is there a way to write it into a one-liner without multiple iterations?

Comment: @Ckkn Given the requirements I would say no. You could rewrite it to construct two lists for one iteration, however, you would increase your memory consumption. Remember, two runs of a linear time complexity  operation `O(n)` is still `O(n)`. ie) `O(2n) = O(n)`